# Why is the primitive cube root of unity used in Cardano's formula?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

From the proof of Cardano's formula on https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Cardano%27s_Formula,

> $$S = \sqrt [3] {R + \sqrt {Q^3 + R^2} }$$
> $$T = \sqrt [3] {R - \sqrt {Q^3 + R^2} }$$
> From Roots of Complex Number, we have the three cube roots of $u^3$ and $v^3$:
> $$u = \begin{cases}
> & S \\
> ( {-\dfrac 1 2 + \dfrac {i \sqrt 3} 2} )& S \\
> ({-\dfrac 1 2 - \dfrac {i \sqrt 3} 2}) & S \\
> \end{cases}
> $$
> $$
> v = \begin{cases}
> & T \\
> ({-\dfrac 1 2 + \dfrac {i \sqrt 3} 2} )& T \\
> ({-\dfrac 1 2 - \dfrac {i \sqrt 3} 2}) & T \\
> \end{cases}
> $$

Where $\omega={-\dfrac 1 2 + \dfrac {i \sqrt 3} 2}$ is the primitive cube root of unity

What is the rationale for using the primitive cube root of unity?

Comment: complex numbers have three cube roots

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the proof they arrive to $u^3= R+\sqrt{Q^3+R^2}$. Since you are looking for all solutions, you need to consider all the three cubic roots of $R+\sqrt{Q^3+R^2}$.

If $r$ is a cubic root of a complex number $z$, then the other two are $\omega r$ and $\omega^2r$ since $(\omega r)^3 = \omega^3 r^3 = 1 z=z$ and $(\omega^2 r)^3 = (\omega^3)^2 r^3 = 1^2 z=z$.